# Failed to run curl 7.83.0 on alpine

Tags: linux, curl, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install **curl** in **7.83** on an alpine environment but it fails to run the command and give me the following error

```
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_easy_nextheader: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_easy_header: symbol not found
```

I've seen in documentation that they are new features, but don't find if it's possible to disable them or fix them.

I've tried the `--enable-headers-api` but it doesn't change anything.

Any idea ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try an `apk update`  and `apk upgrade` to fix missing librairies ?

As describe [here](https://gist.github.com/so0k/3f0546be5f06431a55a0a90ac9c25da8) the issue came from missing librairies on you alpine distribution.

```
bash-4.3# apk update
bash-4.3# apk upgrade

bash-4.3# apk add -U curl
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing curl (7.58.0-r1)
Executing busybox-1.24.2-r13.trigger
OK: 430 MiB in 145 packages
bash-4.3# curl
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_type: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_data: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_data_cb: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_name: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_encoder: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_headers: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_init: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_filedata: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_free: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_subparts: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_filename: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/curl: curl_mime_addpart: symbol not found

bash-4.3# apk upgrade
Upgrading critical system libraries and apk-tools:
(1/1) Upgrading apk-tools (2.6.8-r1 -> 2.6.9-r0)
Executing busybox-1.24.2-r13.trigger
Continuing the upgrade transaction with new apk-tools:
(1/29) Upgrading musl (1.1.14-r14 -> 1.1.14-r16)
(2/29) Upgrading busybox (1.24.2-r13 -> 1.24.2-r14)
Executing busybox-1.24.2-r14.post-upgrade
...
(9/29) Upgrading libcurl (7.52.1-r2 -> 7.58.0-r1)
...
OK: 427 MiB in 145 packages
bash-4.3# curl
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Comment: Just `apk upgrade` was necessary.